# Fetch point data from image WMS

Tags: geoserver, javascript, openlayers, web-mapping, getfeatureinfo

Based on the previous questions I asked, I got a way to fetch the clicked point information, but I want the exact value of gray_index, but as you can see the answer is text or HTML. In the image below, you can see the answer in the console as below.
[image]

Gere is my layer code :

```
const UnTiled = new ol.layer.Image({
        opacity:0.9,
        title:'UnTiled',
        source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
            ratio: 1,
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/world/wms',
            params: {
                     'VERSION': '1.1.1',  
                  "STYLES": '',
                  "LAYERS": '       world:world',
                  "exceptions": 'application/vnd.ogc.se_inimage',
            }
        
          })
          
        });
```

and here is my function for fetching data :

```
map.on('singleclick', function(evt) {
    document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = '';
    var view = map.getView();
    var viewResolution = view.getResolution();
    var url = UnTiled.getSource().getFeatureInfoUrl(
        evt['coordinate'],
        viewResolution,
        'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326',
        {'INFO_FORMAT': 'application/json'}
      );
      console.log(url);
      if (url) {
        fetch(url)
          .then(function (response) { return response.text(); })
          .then(function (html) {
            html;
            console.log(html)
          });
      }
      
     });
```

The URLs are like:

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/world/wms?0=E&1=P&2=S&3=G&4=%3A&5=4&6=3&7=2&8=6&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&QUERY_LAYERS=%09%09world%3Aworld&STYLES=&LAYERS=%09%09world%3Aworld&exceptions=application%2Fvnd.ogc.se_inimage&X=50&Y=50&SRS=EPSG%3A3857&WIDTH=101&HEIGHT=101&BBOX=5203235.632400199%2C3561089.2605374325%2C5697324.583235578%2C4055178.2113728123
```

Comment: can you add the exact URL that is sent to the server and the actual **text** that is returned from it

Comment: this is one of urls that gives me a text :[link](http://localhost:8080/geoserver/world/wms?0=E&1=P&2=S&3=G&4=%3A&5=4&6=3&7=2&8=6&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&QUERY_LAYERS=%09%09world%3Aworld&STYLES=&LAYERS=%09%09world%3Aworld&exceptions=application%2Fvnd.ogc.se_inimage&X=50&Y=50&SRS=EPSG%3A3857&WIDTH=101&HEIGHT=101&BBOX=5203235.632400199%2C3561089.2605374325%2C5697324.583235578%2C4055178.2113728123)

Comment: please use the [edit] button to modify your question

Comment: ok . done , chek it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is not correctly setting the `info_format` so you get the default format (`text/html`). This is because you are setting too many arguments in:

```
var url = UnTiled.getSource().getFeatureInfoUrl(
    evt['coordinate'],
    viewResolution,
    'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326',
    {'INFO_FORMAT': 'application/json'}
  );
```

which should be

```
 var url = UnTiled.getSource().getFeatureInfoUrl(
    evt['coordinate'],
    viewResolution,
    'EPSG:3857', 
    {'INFO_FORMAT': 'application/json'}
  );
```

Comment: Oooh , thanks . now when i put consol.log(html) out put is : `code```{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","id":"","geometry":null,"properties":{"GRAY_INDEX":183}}],"totalFeatures":"unknown","numberReturned":1,"timeStamp":"2021-03-03T13:35:19.931Z","crs":null}` 
How do I get gray_index?

Comment: you parse the json and extract the GRAY_INDEX property